# compatibility users between Symfony 2.3 & 1.4

Tags: php, web, symfony-1.4, symfony-2.3

So at my job we have two web sites with the same users to log in.
One web is done with symfony 2.3 the other 1.4 and my boss asked me to make possible change between web sites without have to log in again.

I don't have any idea of how start or which is the usual way of do this, some tips?

Answer (score 0):

You have two sites, and every site have different session, so you can't do it using only the sites. You will need some third party session manager for to achieve this.

Comment: If they live on different domains, yes. If they are two applications that resides in the same domain, they can share cookies.

Comment: They are in the same domain. It's automatic? or I have to make a function in each side to autolog in? I'm prety new in this of users and security